# Excel Vba Throwing While Setting Object Property Even When Using Set - Error 91

Tags: excel, vba, class, set

It is my first experience with class modules, and while I'm working, Error 91 occured when I'm setting the property. I searched for it, and learnt that I should use set. However, even while I'm using set, it throws "Object Variable Not Set" . And the last thing is, I'm not talking about commented lines.

My Module:

```
    Option Explicit
Public Static Sub VeriGetir()

    Sheets("Veri Sayfası").Activate

    Dim römorklar() As Römork
    Dim index As Integer
    index = -1
    Dim i

    For i = 2 To 100
        If Not Cells(1, i) = "" And Not Cells(12, i) = "" Then
            Dim vRömork As Römork
            Set vRömork = New Römork
            vRömork.ÜrünKodu = Cells(1, i)
            Dim öz As MetinÖzellik
            Set öz = New MetinÖzellik
            öz.Ayarla "asd", 12
            Set vRömork.DingilSayısı = öz 'Error here
            'Set vRömork.Ton = Cells(3, i)
            'Set vRömork.En = Cells(4, i)
            'Set vRömork.Boy = Cells(5, i)
            'Set vRömork.KüçükYük = Cells(6, i)
            'Set vRömork.İlave1 = Cells(7, i)
            'Set vRömork.İlave2 = Cells(8, i)
            'Set vRömork.ÖnAks = Cells(9, i)
            'Set vRömork.ArkaAks = Cells(10, i)
            'Set vRömork.Jant = Cells(11, i)
            'Set vRömork.Lastik = Cells(12, i)
            'index = index + 1
            'ReDim römorklar(index)
            'römorklar(index) = vRömork
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
Public Function MetinOluştur(isim As String, fiyat As Double) As MetinÖzellik

    Dim özellik As MetinÖzellik
    Set özellik = New MetinÖzellik

    özellik.Ayarla isim, fiyat

    Set MetinOluştur = özellik

End Function
Public Static Function SayıOluştur(değer As Double, fiyat As Double) As SayıÖzellik

    Dim sayı_özellik As SayıÖzellik
    Set sayı_özellik = New SayıÖzellik

    sayı_özellik.Ayarla değer, fiyat

    Set SayıOluştur = sayı_özellik

End Function
```

Römork Class Module:

```
    Option Explicit
    Private pÜrünKodu As String
    Private pDingilSayısı As MetinÖzellik
    Private pTon As MetinÖzellik
    Private pEn As SayıÖzellik
    Private pBoy As SayıÖzellik
    Private pKüçükYük As SayıÖzellik
    Private pİlave1 As SayıÖzellik
    Private pİlave2 As SayıÖzellik
    Private pÖnAks As MetinÖzellik
    Private pArkaAks As MetinÖzellik
    Private pJant As MetinÖzellik
    Private pLastik As MetinÖzellik
    Public Property Get ÜrünKodu() As String
        ÜrünKodu = pÜrünKodu
    End Property
    Public Property Let ÜrünKodu(Value As String)
        pÜrünKodu = Value
    End Property
    Public Property Get DingilSayısı() As MetinÖzellik
        DingilSayısı = pDingilSayısı
    End Property
    Public Property Let DingilSayısı(Value As MetinÖzellik)
        pDingilSayısı = Value
    End Property
    Public Property Get Ton() As MetinÖzellik
        Ton = pTon
    End Property
    Public Property Let Ton(Value As MetinÖzellik)
        pTon = Value
    End Property
    Public Property Get ÖnAks() As MetinÖzellik
        ÖnAks = pÖnAks
    End Property
    Public Property Let ÖnAks(Value As MetinÖzellik)
        pÖnAks = Value
    End Property
    Public Property Get ArkaAks() As MetinÖzellik
        ArkaAks = pArkaAks
    End Property
    Public Property Let ArkaAks(Value As MetinÖzellik)
        pArkaAks = Value
    End Property
    Public Property Get Jant() As MetinÖzellik
        Jant = pJant
    End Property
    Public Property Let Jant(Value As MetinÖzellik)
        pJant = Value
    End Property
    Public Property Get Lastik() As MetinÖzellik
        Lastik = pLastik
    End Property
    Public Property Let Lastik(Value As MetinÖzellik)
        pLastik = Value
    End Property
    ' En  Boy K.Yük   İlave1  İlave2
    Public Property Get En() As SayıÖzellik
        En = pEn
    End Property
    Public Property Let En(Value As SayıÖzellik)
        pEn = Value
    End Property
    Public Property Get Boy() As SayıÖzellik
        Boy = pBoy
    End Property
    Public Property Let Boy(Value As SayıÖzellik)
        pBoy = Value
    End Property
    Public Property Get KüçükYük() As SayıÖzellik
        KüçükYük = pKüçükYük
    End Property
    Public Property Let KüçükYük(Value As SayıÖzellik)
        pKüçükYük = Value
    End Property
    Public Property Get İlave1() As SayıÖzellik
        İlave = pİlave1
    End Property
    Public Property Let İlave1(Value As SayıÖzellik)
        pİlave1 = Value
    End Property
    Public Property Get İlave2() As SayıÖzellik
        İlave2 = pİlave2
    End Property
    Public Property Let İlave2(Value As SayıÖzellik)
        İlave2 = Value
    End Property
```

MetinÖzellik Class Module:

```
Option Explicit
Private pİsim As String
Private pFiyat As Double
Public Property Get İsim() As String
    İsim = pİsim
End Property
Public Property Let İsim(Value As String)
    pİsim = Value
End Property
Public Property Get fiyat() As Double
    fiyat = pFiyat
End Property
Public Property Let fiyat(Value As Double)
    pFiyat = Value
End Property
Public Sub Ayarla(pİsim As String, pFiyat As Double)
    Me.İsim = pİsim
    Me.fiyat = pFiyat
End Sub
```

SayıÖzellik Class Module:

```
Option Explicit
Private pDeğer As Double
Private pFiyat As Double
Public Property Get değer() As String
    değer = pDeğer
End Property
Public Property Let değer(Value As String)
    pDeğer = Value
End Property
Private pFiyat As Double
Public Property Get fiyat() As Double
    fiyat = pFiyat
End Property
Public Property Let fiyat(Value As Double)
    pFiyat = Value
End Property
Public Sub Ayarla(pDeğer As Double, pFiyat As Double)
    Me.değer = pDeğer
    Me.fiyat = pFiyat
End Sub
Public Static Function Oluştur(değer As Double, fiyat As Double) As SayıÖzellik

    Dim sayı_özellik As SayıÖzellik
    Set sayı_özellik = New SayıÖzellik

    sayı_özellik.Ayarla değer, fiyat

    Set Oluştur = sayı_özellik

End Function
```

Comment: Which line causes the error ?

Comment: `Public Property Let DingilSayısı(Value As MetinÖzellik)` >> `Public Property Set DingilSayısı(Value As MetinÖzellik)`

Comment: Still gives an error. :(

Comment: `pDingilSayısı = Value` -> `Set pDingilSayısı = Value`

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you so much. But I don't get the difference between let and set.

Comment: `Let` is for non-object variables and `Set` for object variables

Comment: You saved my day! Also you deserve an accepted answer, I can mark it as correct answer if you post :)

Comment: of course the same applies for all other cases where you're setting an object `property`. For instance `pTon = Value` -> `Set pTon = Value`, `pÖnAks = Value` -> `Set pÖnAks = Value` and so on

Comment: You need to use `Set` when assigning the return value from the `Property Get` procedure

Comment: @TimWilliams I noticed that, thanks!